# Shrinking div on Click - Jquery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I want a particular div to shrink, (Complete data should be visible) every time when user clicks on the particular icon. Here I have the class, **legend-icon**. so I want the anotherID,for example ***#Chart*** to shrink when user click

HTML

```
<div id="id1">
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="legend-icon"></i> <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <div id="legend_container" class="dropdown-menu">
        <div id="smoother" title="Smoothing"></div><div id="legend"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="in">
   <div id="chart">

    //my data

   </div>
</div>
```

I tried like

```
  $("i.legend-icon").click(function(){
    $("#chart").animate({width: '-=50px',},"slow");
    });
```

But It`s not working. It`s completely not displaying the div to -50px.. But I just want the div to shrink What should I do here?

Comment: Yess... It`s hiding the data to -50px.. but not shrinking..

Comment: Typo over here: `<div id="id1>` should be `<div id="id1">`

Comment: @Axel Noted.. that was a typo! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Could you show your css for this elements to?

you can check my [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyukD/), it works as you expect. But its not with your html and css, but it should be the same.

```
<a href="#" class="click-me">click me</a>

<div class="animate-me"></div>


.animate-me {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}


$(".click-me").click(function(){
    $(".animate-me").animate({width: '-=50px',},"slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Dejan... Thanks for your response..  It is completely removing the chart present in the div -50px.. So I want it to be there... And also clicking the same div again should return the div (chart) back to normal position.. Is it possible?

Comment: Drop down menu also not responding(i.e it`s not showing the <li> data inside the drop down..) it`s responding only to click..

Comment: Just so I get this straight. A click should minimise the `div#cart` with `-50px`, and a click again should restore it to it's original width?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine....

Maybe just try a bigger value, it really depends on how big your element is...

In my example, its 500px wide, and I shrink it 450...

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/7xDke/)

```
 $("i.legend-icon").click(function(){
$("#chart").animate({width: '-=450px',},"slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to be more specific on what you want the container to be after shrinking. animat can have much more controls:

```
  ... animate(
                        {
                            "left":<positionafter shrinking>,
                            "width":["toggle", "swing"]
                        },
                        {
                            "duration": 0,
                            "step": function( now, fx ){},
                            "complete": function(){
```

have a look at the animate doc on the details.